# CSS using images instead of bullets

Tags: css, html-lists

I want to use three different images instead of bullets to create a lisli>t

Example:

```
<ul>
    <li>The dog is big</li>
    <li>The dog is small</li>
    <li>The dog is medium sized</li>
</ul>
```

So instead of bullets before each of the above phrases there would be a different image
before each.

Answer (score 17):

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/dMfcf/)

This makes use of the CSS property [`list-style-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/list-style-image).

```css
ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 32px;
  line-height: 1.5
}

.b1 {
  list-style-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Icons-mini-icon_attachment.gif);
}

.b2 {
  list-style-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/Icons-mini-icon_security.gif);
}

.b3 {
  list-style-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Icons-mini-icon_clock.gif);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="b1">The dog is big</li>
  <li class="b2">The dog is small</li>
  <li class="b3">The dog is medium sized</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use list-style-image: url(imagename); to replace the bullets entirely with images. The downside of this method is that each browsers positions the images differently. CSS background images for list bullets is a more consistent method.

from http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/vertical04.htm

Answer (score 2):

you can use the **list-style-image** property.

```
ul.dogbig
{
  list-style-image:url("/images/dogbig.gif");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is such a property of CSS but i think that it doesn't work for every different `<li>` element:

```
ul
{
list-style-image:url("/images/blueball.gif");
list-style-type:square;
}
```

I hope it would help you